# aws-sdk nodejs socket timeout after successful aws lambda run

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am running aws-sdk 2.1500 on nodejs client and run the AWS-Lambda
AWS-Lambda ended successfully (in aws lambda logfile), but the nodejs client didn't receive any reponse and is still working until timeout.

Any idea what should I check ?
Or is there a way to debug connection to see what is happening underneath ?

```
            const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
                httpOptions: {
                    connectTimeout: LAMBDA_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS,
                    timeout: LAMBDA_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS, // = 15min
                },
                maxRetries: 0,
            });


    try {
        response = await lambda
            .invoke({
                FunctionName: lambdaName,
                Payload: payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : undefined,
            }, (err, data) => {
                    if (err){
                        console.error(`Could not invoke lambda: \n ${err}`);
                    }
                }
            )

            .promise();
    } catch (e) {
           ...
    }
```

ERROR STACK:
at ClientRequest. (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:87:34)
at ClientRequest. (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:87:34)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (node:_http_client:840:9)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:589:8)
2023-12-08T15:48:55.864+01:00   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it can help to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help you whitout a way its can be reproduces the error, but its sound as you have some node app running inside lambda and try to keep it running, if that's the case i will not recommend this way to use a Lambda function, its build to start application, run your code and the close the app down.

If you application should run take a look on ECS, build your application as a container and push it to ECR, or spin a EC2 instance up and try a sample out here.

Late me know about its your case or I'm total wrong?

Comment: No, AWS Lambda has some python code that completes successfully before timeout (at least that is what I see in CW logs).
I suppose that the nodejs client that called the AWS Lambda was not notified by that fact and it keeps running until it hits timeout.

Comment: Lambda works with its execute some code, the only way your Lambda hit timeout if your code take to long, lambda are not a app its function trigger method. - can you mabey describe the flow around the function with expected incoming/outcoming  and what services you use?

Comment: The timeout is seen in the client - it's a socket timeout. 
The AWS lambda itself ended successfully.
I've included error stack but the error is thrown around 5 minutes AFTER lambda completion, so the problem is that the client silently ignores response from AWS.

Comment: ...or it never received response from the AWS.